# my response is coming just up to now

Tags: adverbs

*First of all, let me apologize that my response is coming **just up to now**.*

I would like to ask a native speaker whether the sentence makes sense, especially the bolded part. I would like to express that my reaction is coming too late and that the addressee had to wait.

Comment: "just up to now" is hard to understand. A native speaker might say "...that my response didn't come until now" or "...that I didn't respond until now". Also, "apologize that" is unusual, so a native would say "let me apologize *for* not responding until now."

Comment: Much better phrases are *my response is* ***coming (just) now*** or *my response is* ***coming up (just) now***. The use of **to** is wrong, and **coming just up** is also very strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your construction is not idiomatic English although people might understand what you mean.

It would be better to phrase your apology in terms such as these.

> First of all, let me apologize for my late/belated/overdue response.
>   First of all, please allow me to apologize for my .......
>   First of all, may I apologize for my ......

Comment: which of late/belated/overdue is the least formal here? (thank you)

Comment: **Late** is the least formal although there is little to choose between them.